# Setting new instance with existing boot disk as previous ran out of memory

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, deviceid

I'm hoping someone can help me on this.

I have filled up a server and now i can't get in it.  Support gave me the following instructions (except miss out number 4) but I'm come to a halt.

I can't get the code to work.  How do i find out my device ID and partition number?

1. Stop VM (Original)
2. Click edit into your instance (Detach the boot disk) then save
3. then Create new VM
4. Add the disk of original VM in new VM as (existing disk which is relay-3) then click create
5. Then SSH to new VM
6. Perform extend method(growpart) on the additional disk. Please follow this documentation[1]:

sudo growpart /dev/DEVICE_ID PARTITION_NUMBER

Note:  Please skip the number 4 step and just follow the step 1 to 7.

7. Then mount to a directory
8. Then execute resize2fs to newly mounted filesystem

sudo resize2fs /dev/DEVICE_IDPARTITION_NUMBER

9. Once successfully extended, unmount the filesystem
10. Then Detach additional disk
11. Then Re-attach it as boot disk in the original VM

Thanks

Comment: Hi Josh, please, next time, give us a little more specifics. What VM provider, what exactly can't you perform, what errors you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

For determining your device paths, use `mount` command (without other args), to get a list of mounted devices. Your root device is mounted to `/`, your home device (if other than root) is mounted to `/home` etc...

For listing more information about disk volumes, use `sudo blkid`. It gives you a list of disk devices and their UUIDs.

```sh
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="62bd22ec-c451-4a95-8c36-d6669c677005" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="00006a5a-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="68eed4f2-4b04-4f72-a340-acaf83226839" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00006a5a-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="93615346-58dc-4e5c-a3a9-2eb5017a09b3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d95b3f78-8a2b-49dc-af16-7a10d9c7ad16"
```

Comment: I'm using Google Cloud Platform.  

The SSH won't open because I'm told the disk is full.  We tried OSLogin and serial login but both failed (serial i think because i have 2FA)

Support gavce me the instructions above, but i can't get it to work.

I've detached the boot disk from the instance but that's as far as I've got

Comment: Have you at least got to step 5?

Comment: Currently, I'm stuck on 7